# Is it possibile to create a Typescript module that export mixins?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I need to create a npm local module in typescript that export more Vue Mixins, than I need to use them on another typescript project.

Any example or starter project?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation obviously depends on the library you are using.

But you can extract all the code of your mixin into another component/file. Both versions are using the library [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component).

**Version 1**

```js
@Component
export default class MyMixins extends Vue {}
```

and then use inheritance in a child component:

```js
@Component
export default class ChildClass extends MyMixins {}
```

**Version 2**

You can use the `mixins` function:

```js
import Component, { mixins } from 'vue-class-component'

@Component()
export default class ChildClass extends mixins(MyMixin1, MyMixin2) {}
```

For reference, you can use the [document](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/extend-and-mixins.html#extend).

Comment: the problem is that if I import Mixins from library and user version 2, it do not see variables and functions of mixin, if i create the same mixin in probject without library it works.